# Fade in button at certain scrolling point

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please bear with me with this two-part question for help. I have this button which scrolls up to a certain point and opens a div. The following code does what I need

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="FilterResults" class="FilterResults">Filter Results</button>

var x = document.getElementById('filterresults');

function myFunction(){
    if (x.style.display === 'block'){
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    }
    $('html, body').scrollTop($('#up').offset().top);
}
```

What I need to add is for the button to fade in/out at a certain scroll point, I have the following code for a fade in/out, but I am unsure how to marry the two parts of the code together

```
$(function () {
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
        $('.FilterResults').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.FilterResults').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

css

```
 #FilterResults {
   display: none;
   position:fixed;
   bottom:10px;
   left:100px;
   font-size:16px;
   text-align:center;
   outline: none;
   z-index:9999;
   border: none;
   background-color: #4399fc;
   color: white;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding: 6px;
   border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Jason

The problem is I do NOT know how I add BOTH sets of code together, so this it is one complete code (if you know what I mean).

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do as the end result. I don't understand what your `myFunction` is trying to do. If button is block, you set it to block, else you set it to block? What does that mean?

Comment: myFunction() opens and closes the hidden div

Comment: use http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/ `waypoints` library

Comment: use [`window.scrollY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY) instead of `.scrollTop`.

Comment: Working plunker using your code with slight modifications: https://plnkr.co/edit/E1EfxRQpL4458c1WGCFm?p=preview

Comment: @NiK648 Thank you so much, a slight modification and it does exactly what is required. Thanks again. Jason

Comment: Just as a side note: You should take a look at the console in the dev tools of your Browser (F12 in Chrome & Firefox). That way you can detect errors like missing brackets easily.